# move_uploaded_file only works in subdirectories

Tags: php, file-upload, path, php-7

I have a upload-script that is supposed to upload files the following way:

```
html
|----folder1
     |----folder2 <- where files should go
|----upload
     |----index.php <- uploadSkript
```

I want to move the uploaded file to folder2

```
if (isset ( $_FILES['portfolio'])) {
$uploaddir = '../folder1/folder2/';

switch($_FILES['portfolio']['error'] ) {
    ....
}

if (is_dir($uploaddir) && is_writable($uploaddir)) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['portfolio']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$_FILES['portfolio']['name']); ...
```

This worked, but since I migrated to php7 it wont work anymore.

I can move the file in the same folder as the index.php or to subdirectories.
But when I try using ../folder1/folder2/ or /html/folder1/folder2/ to get to folder2 (or anywhere else which is not a subdirectory) it wont move the file.
is_dir reports false.
Thank you for your help/ideas

Comment: Check the directory permissions, make sure the web user has write permission.

Comment: Hi, thank you, tried that already, folder1 and 2 both have write permission.
Should be irrelevant for is_dir anyway.?

Comment: You're missing a `/` in the concatenation `$uploaddir.$_FILES['portfolio']['name']`.

Comment: Ah yes @Barmar the '/' is in $uploaddir, updated code snippet

Comment: Turn on full error reporting to see the reason for the failure. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions guys.
I could solve my problem by deactivating open_basedir in my php7-options. :)